# Porque não consigo pegar os dados da requisição ajax? (json)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Tenho o seguinte código:

script.js:

```
function maisDetalhes(id){
$.ajax({
url:'paginaDados.php',
type:'GET',
data:'id='+id,
dataType:'json',
success:function(data){
   alert(data.id_event);
 }
});
```

e no paginaDados.php:

```
foreach ($Dados as $Linhas) {      
  $resultado = array("id_evento" => $Linhas['id_event'],
  "nome_evento" => $Linhas['event_name'] );    
}

echo json_encode($resultado);

exit();
```

Porém na função sucess do ajax, eu não estou conseguindo receber os dados, quando dou o alert ele mostra 'undefined', quando eu escrevo só alert(data) ele aparece tudo, porém eu gostaria de pegar separadamente os dados, como eu posso fazer?

Muito obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso porque a variável data não é um objeto JSON e sim uma String. Para transforma-la em Objeto usa-se o parse JSON do JavaScript deste modo:

```
function maisDetalhes(id){
    $.ajax({
       url:'paginaDados.php',
       type:'GET',
       data:'id='+id,
       dataType:'json',
       success:function(data){
          var obj = JSON.parse(data);
          alert(obj.id_event);
       }
    });

}
```

Comment: Putssss, muito obrigado cara, de verdade, sou bem leigo com ajax, e tava quebrando a cabeça pra tentar resolver isso, muito obrigado mesmo

Comment: Sugiro que uses Firebug no Firefox, e em vez de usar o alert use console.log, pois assim o debuger diz que tipo de variável está chegando. Foi um prazer ajuda-lo.