# Por que a função Json_encode () PHP, não está retornando dados no formato Json?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, codeigniter

Bom Dia. Após 2 dias inteiros pesquisando venho postar minha pergunta:
Por que o comando

```
echo json_encode($a);
```

está retornando uma pagina HTML ?
É um cadastro onde tenho 1 chave estrangeira, mas o usuário não vai digitar a chave estrangeira ( lógico ) e sim 3 dados que serão pesquisados no Mysql para saber se a TURMA existe ou não. Com isso, tenho que usar o Javascript.

Estou usando CODEIGNITER. 
Então no footer eu tenho o codigo:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#btgravar").click(function(){

        var nturma = $("#nturma").val();
        var cletivo = $("#cletivo").val();
        var csemestre = $("#csemestre").val();
        alert(nturma);
        $.ajax({
           url: 'Planodeaula/ajaxrequestpost',
           type: 'POST',
           data: {nturma: nturma, cletivo: cletivo, csemestre:csemestre},
           contentType: ('application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'),
           accepts: {json: "json"},
           //dataType: 'json',
           success: function(a) {
               //console.log(retorno);
               alert(a);
                //var resposta = jQuery.parseJSON(retorno);
                var resposta = JSON.parse(a);
                alert(resposta);
                if(resposta === 'true')
                {
                    alert("tudo funcionando 100%.");
                }else{
                    alert("NÃO funcionando !!!!!!!!!!!");
                }
           },
           error:function( jqXHR , textStatus, errorThrown )
            {
              alert("Erro: "+textStatus);
              //alert(jqXHR);
              alert("Detalhes do erro: "+errorThrown);
           }
        });
    });
});


</script>
```

Se eu coloco o comando no javascript dataType: 'json'; retorna aquele "famoso" erro "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0”" ao retira-lo retorna a pagina toda em HTML.
No Controller ( eu inventei , depois de 1.000.000 de tentativas, um array falso para transformar em Json ).O certo é ir até o MODEL this->dia->check_turma(), verificar se existe no banco e retornar para o Controller:

```
public function ajaxrequestpost() 
{    
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nturma','trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cletivo','trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('csemestre','trim|required');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        $a = array("tipo"=>$tipo, "rua"=>$rua, "bairro"=>$bairro, "cidade"=>$cidade, "cep"=>$cep, "uf"=>$uf);
        $a = utf8_encode($a);
        echo json_encode($a);
        exit;
        //return $a;
    }
    else{
        //show_error('Dados válidos!');
        //$retorno=$this->dia->check_turma();
        header('Content-type: application/json');
       $a = array("tipo"=>$tipo, "rua"=>$rua, "bairro"=>$bairro, "cidade"=>$cidade, "cep"=>$cep, "uf"=>$uf);
       $a = utf8_encode($a);
       echo json_encode($a);
       exit;


    }
}
```

Já testei no codigo Javascript:

dataType: 'json'

accepts: {json: "json"},

E no PHP :
header('Content-type: application/json');

Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$data = utf8_encode($data);

exit;

Pesquisei :
[Requisição ajax não está funcionando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37819/requisi%c3%a7%c3%a3o-ajax-n%c3%a3o-est%c3%a1-funcionando)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254891/what-does-content-type-application-json-charset-utf-8-really-mean

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280274/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0

[Requisição ajax não está funcionando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37819/requisi%c3%a7%c3%a3o-ajax-n%c3%a3o-est%c3%a1-funcionando)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572721/ajax-call-returning-data-but-failing

[Array não é convertido para JSON](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59466/array-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-convertido-para-json)

[Porque não consigo pegar os dados da requisição ajax? (json)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/153333/porque-n%C3%A3o-consigo-pegar-os-dados-da-requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ajax-json)

https://makitweb.com/send-ajax-request-codeigniter/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script

https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/jquery-ajax-request-example-in-codeigniterexample.html

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/154095/revisions

Comment: Se a página requisitada `ajaxrequestpost` tiver tags HTML irá retornar tb junto com o JSON do echo, e isso resultará em erro. A única coisa que deve retornar da página é o que o echo imprime.

Comment: Obrigado vou testar. Esse método  ajaxrequestpost fica dentro de um Controller. E no index do Controller tenho a chamada a 3 views. Cabeçalho, menu_lateral e Rodapé. Então, terei que tirar esse método desse Controller e criar outro Controller para inclui-lo. Correto ?

Comment: O arquivo requisitado não pode ser uma página normal (com tags e tudo). Se for preciso crie um arquivo .php só com o código PHP e o echo.

Comment: A função `json_encode()` não é o problema, o problema é o dado que você está passando para ele codificar, vc não deveria user `utf8_encode()` num array? O parâmetro para [utf8_encode deve ser string](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-encode.php).

Comment: Sinceramente, eu , após 2 dias , coloquei essa função utf8_encode(), lendo algumas dicas. Mas o problema é que retorna o HTML ( como sitou o Sam , não posso ter tags no arquivo onde está o echo json_encode). Então , criei um .php puro e vou inserir a function ( metodo ) para ver o resultado. Observe que o array é "falso" , já no desespero de forçar um retorno um json e não um HTML. Vou seguir também a sua dica e retira-la.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1- Criei um PHP como citou o @Sam.
2- Retire a função utf8_encode() @Ivan Ferrer do codigo PHP.
3- Inseri a função stringfy var resposta = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)).
4- Formatei o parametro data da forma correta :

> data: {'nturma': nturma  ,'csemestre':csemestre ,'cletivo':cletivo}

5- Acho que irrelevante troquei o objeto e o evento que dispara o javascript para :

> $("#csemestre").change(function()

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#csemestre").change(function(){
        var base_url = '<?php echo base_url()?>';   
        var nturma = $("#nturma").val();
        var cletivo = $("#cletivo").val();
        var csemestre = $("#csemestre").val();
        console.log(nturma);
        console.log(csemestre);
        console.log(cletivo);
        $.ajax({
           url: base_url+'Requisicoes/ajaxrequestpost',
           type: 'POST',
           contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
           accepts: {json: "json"},
           dataType: 'json',
           data: {'nturma': nturma  ,'csemestre':csemestre ,'cletivo':cletivo},
           success: function(data) {
               console.log(data);
                //var resposta = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                var resposta = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
                console.log(resposta);
                if(resposta === 'true')
                {
                    alert("tudo funcionando 100%.");
                }else{
                    alert("NÃO funcionando !!!!!!!!!!!");
                }
           },
           error:function( jqXHR , textStatus, errorThrown )
            {
              alert("Erro: "+textStatus);
              console.log(arguments);
              //alert(jqXHR);
              alert("Detalhes do erro: "+errorThrown);
           }
        });
    });
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está passando um array para o `utf8_encode($data)`, isso é um erro: `expects parameter 1 to be string`, ele não vai devolver o array convertido, e neste caso também não vai chegar no `json_encode($data)`.

Se você precisa converter para utf8_encode seu array, use uma função auxiliar, exemplo:
`$data = array_map('utf8_encode',$data);`

A função `utf8_encode()` só recebe string como parâmetro, [mais informação aqui](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-encode.php).

No caso do CodeIgniter é preciso utilizar as regras do framework, exemplo:

```
return $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')
                    ->set_status_header(200)
                    ->set_output(json_encode($data));
```

Comment: Sim Ivan, vou retirar. Criei um novo arquivo php. No browser chamando esse arquivo, estou com o tendo como resposta ( aquele array que criei só para verificar o retorno {"tipo":"APARTAMENTO","rua":"BAR\u00c3O DE MIRACEMA","bairro":"CENTRO","cidade":"CAMPOS DOS GOYTACAZES"}). Mas tem algo errado pois dentro do site ( com estrutura MVC - CODEIGNITER) ainda está retornando html.

Comment: Edite sua pergunta com as novas modificações que você fez para que a gente entenda qual o problema.

Comment: As vezes o problema é que você está tentando enviar isso para uma view, o que não é o caso.

Comment: Bom Dia @Ivan Ferrer. Eu respondi ontem como eu resolvi o problema. A resposta está logo abaixo.Só não sei marcar como "RESOLVIDO"